# Can if-structures be used in Haskell list comprehensions?

Tags: if-statement, haskell, list-comprehension

Can some sort of `if` statement be used inside list comprehension to determine one of several outcomes for each element of a list?

Say I have a list comprehension over a list that contains elements which are either a `0` or a `1`.

If the value is a `0`, then the string `"off"` needs to be stored in another list in the same position. If the value is `1` then `"on"`.

This is just an example. It looks easily done with recursion, but what if this needs to be done on a list of lists? Or lists of lists of lists?

Comment: clarify your general question please, it is unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course you can:

```
on_or_off_list xs = [if x == 0 then "off" else "on" | x <- xs]
```

Or in a more point-free style:

```
on_or_off 0 = "off"
on_or_off _ = "on"
on_or_off_list = map on_or_off
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using mutually-exclusive tests in singleton lists with guards:

```
foo :: (Num a, Eq a) => [a] -> [String]
foo xs = [s | x <- xs, s <- ["off" | x==0] ++ ["on" | x==1]]
```

Or you could just use the `if` expression directly,

```
bar :: (Num a, Eq a) => [a] -> [String]
bar xs = [s | x <- xs, let s = if x==0 then "off" else "on"]
```

This answers your specific question.

Comment: `[["on","off"] !! fromEnum (x == 0) | x <- xs]` :3

Comment: finally had to look up that colon-three emoticon. :) I get what you're saying, but my first instinct is to avoid the "if" and the "then" and the "else", if I can. what I should've written is actually `s <- take 1 $ ["off" | x==0] ++ ["on"]`. and I always forget about the multi-way if, which is a nice compromise between verbosity and visuality, but _can_ be quite confusing inside LC.

Comment: I guess I misinterpreted the question as asking for a LC way to do the equivalent of `if`, at first; then realized it could be asking about using the `if` itself as is, not "some sort of `if`". I used `let` intentionally, as that way the code is open to further changes more easily, since the question said it is just an example, so, it should be easy to change, I thought.